# bash basename syntax error inside for in loop

Tags: bash

I have a simple script:

```
for photo in $full_path/*.jpg; do
    $b_photo=$(basename $photo)
    echo $b_photo
done
```

it's simplified form of what I'm trying to do, but this gives me error like this:

```
./foo.sh: line 334: =foobar.jpg: command not found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign variables with `var=$(command)` and use them with `$var` (or, better, `${var}`):

```
for photo in $full_path/*.jpg; do
    b_photo=$(basename $photo)       <------ b_photo=$() instead of $b_photo=$()
    echo $b_photo                                                   ^
done
```

Note you can directly write:

```
for photo in $full_path/*.jpg; do
    basename "$photo"
done
```

Comment: Simplified: Fetch value with dollar sign `$var`, assign value with `var=`.

Comment: What's with all the bombast of `echo "$(basename $photo)"`? Write: `basename $photo` which writes the name to standard output.  :D

Comment: @JonathanLeffler +1 for your comment as it reminded me how I learnt the [bombastic word](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPLwSaUpZC4), long time ago :D Thanks by the way, you are completely right. Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the problem [pointed out by fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19590683/68063), `basename $photo` will go wrong if `$photo` contains a space:

```
 $ photo="directory/file name"
 $ basename $photo
 file
```

It will also go wrong if `$photo` starts with a `-`:

```
$ photo="-directory/file"
$ basename $photo
basename: illegal option -- d
usage: basename string [suffix]
       basename [-a] [-s suffix] string [...]
```

You could write:

```
for photo in "$full_path"/*.jpg; do
    basename -- "$photo"
done
```

but a simpler way to carry out this task (printing file names in a directory that match a pattern to standard output, one per line) would be to switch to the directory and use [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf):

```
{ cd -- "$full_path" && printf "%s\n" *.jpg }
```

Comment: The classic and POSIX versions of [`basename`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html)
 have no options, so the `-directory` problem should not arise.  Frankly, the command with the option is broken.  The `basename` on Mac OS X has options `-a` and `-s`.  I'm not convinced this is an enhancement (though the number of times I create files that start with a dash is strictly limited – having said which, I did create a file `-` this morning by accident while checking some shell syntax).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: On FreeBSD, Linux, and OS X, `basename -foo` says "basename: illegal option -- f" so if you care about portability to any of these operating systems, this is a genuine problem!

Comment: Yes; I'm not denying it's a problem. I'm just annoyed to find an unnecessary portability problem.  If we're not careful, they'll fix `tr` so it takes file name arguments (…errr, why hasn't anyone ever done that?).  I suppose I should say 'thanks for the heads up'; it is not you that I'm annoyed with!